# How to pass multiple arguments separately to the next task in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using a templated python file that I import on DAG. I want to pass multiple outputs(lists) generated by the 1st task to the next task. I tried this:

```
def funct1():
    a = ['apple', 'orange']
    b = ['mango', 'lemon']
    return a, b

def funct2(a,b):
    for k in a,
        quote1 = (f"i love {k}!")
        print(quote)
    for x in b,
        quote2 = (f"i love {k}!")
        print(quote2)


dag = DAG("fruits", default_args=default_args)


t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='descr',
    python_callable=filenameoftemplate.funct1,
    dag=dag)


t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='display',
    python_callable=filenameoftemplate.funct2,
    op_kwargs=
    {'a': t1.output,
    'b': t2.output},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

result:

> i love [apple, orange, mango, lemon]!

> i love [apple, orange, mango, lemon]!

> i love [apple, orange, mango, lemon]!

> i love [apple, orange, mango, lemon]!

Thing is, all the returned values are being read as one on the next tasks. How can I pass and pull them as separate arguments? I want the result to be:

i love apple!
i love orange!
i love mango!
i love lemon!

Answer (score 0):

try to use a counter variable to determine access which value

```py
def funct1():
    a = ['apple', 'orange']
    b = ['mango', 'lemon']
    return a, b

# Use counter to determine access which value
counter = 0

def funct2(a,b):
    quote1 = (f"i love {a[counter]}!")
    print(quote1)
    quote2 = (f"i love {b[counter]}!")
    print(quote2)
    counter += 1


dag = DAG("fruits", default_args=default_args)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='descr',
    python_callable=filenameoftemplate.funct1,
    dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='display',
    python_callable=filenameoftemplate.funct2,
    op_kwargs=
    {'a': t1.output,
    'b': t2.output},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)def funct1():
    a = ['apple', 'orange']
    b = ['mango', 'lemon']
    return a, b

# Use counter to determine access which value
counter = 0

def funct2(a,b):
    quote1 = (f"i love {a[counter]}!")
    print(quote1)
    quote2 = (f"i love {b[counter]}!")
    print(quote2)
    counter += 1


dag = DAG("fruits", default_args=default_args)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='descr',
    python_callable=filenameoftemplate.funct1,
    dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='display',
    python_callable=filenameoftemplate.funct2,
    op_kwargs=
    {'a': t1.output,
    'b': t2.output},
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```